# Componentwise differences of vectors as bound of componentwise differences after permutating the indices

Tags: permutations, vectors, order-theory

Let $x,y\in\Bbb R ^N$ and $\pi ^x , \pi ^y \in \mathcal S_N$ such that
$$x_{\pi^x (1)} \geq \ldots \geq x_{\pi^x (N)} ,\quad y_{\pi^y (1)} \geq \ldots \geq y_{\pi^y (N)}.$$

I think there should hold:
$$\max_{k=1,\ldots,N} x_{\pi^x (k)} - y_{\pi^y(k)} \leq \max_{i=1,\ldots,N } x_i - y_i$$

Comment: What is $S_N??$

Comment: The set of permutations on $\{1, \ldots , N \}$.